# Is it possible to play Path of Exile entirely solo?

Tags: path-of-exile

I know that the game doesn't have an offline mode, but at the time being I'd prefer playing entirely solo, without seeing or interacting with other player characters. I have disabled the chat, but players running with glamorous gear and pets add a cluttered feel to the hub areas (assuming that others can't join me on quests without an invitation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest thing you can get is [Solo Self-Found mode](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Solo_Self-Found). In this mode you cannot trade or create parties. However, you will still see other SSF players in towns - that's the way game developers earn money - they sell fancy microtransaction items for players to show off.

You can try playing less popular leagues / platforms. I think Normal (non seasonal) Hardcore SSF on consoles will have the smallest number of players.

Comment: Unfortunately only available in the act 3 and must be set when creating a new character. But sure, for online games the developers essentially decide how people play as modding isn't possible.

Comment: Later in the game, you can avoid towns for 99% of the time and use your own hide-out instead. Once you've completed all 10 acts, there is no need to visit towns at all anymore. (I play Solo Self-Found, as I want to play the game at my own pace)